# Почему не работает google почта для домена?

Tags: email, dns, gmail, яндекс-почта

На почту не приходят письма с ящиков типа info@малопопулярный.ru и приходят с ящиков info@yandex.ru (info@mail.ru).

Как это произошло:

Была почта для домена от Гугла. Перенес сайт на другой хостинг, а нс домену прописал яндексовые:

```
dns1.yandex.net
dns2.yandex.net
```

В управлении dns Яндекс предложил скопировать текущие настройки днс в которых были строки для работы гугл почты, я так и сделал. Сайт заработал на новом хостинге, почта заработала. Но на следующий день почта перестала работать, и в настройках днс пропали все строки упоминания гугла.

В общем, я внес из документации 3-ю и последние 5 строчек. Почта заработала, но появилась проблема, описанная в первом предложении.

[image: скрин записей]

В чем причина, что не приходят письма с некоторых ящиков?

Может виноваты другие записи в днс и их нужно удалить?

Answer (score 1):

Сверьте настройки записей MX с документацией от google

Есть нюанс а работе DNS - многие промежуточные серверы DNS кешируют запросы и время хранения кеша может доходить до двух суток. Таким образом, если ты прописал записи сейчас, то на сервере @малопопулярный.ru они могут появится не сразу. Кроме этого, при невозможности доставки письма, присылается ответ отправителю. Тебе стоит заглянуть в этот ответ, там будет причина - почему не доставлено.

Рекомендую проверить настройки MX и если всё правильно, набраться терпения и проверить через 1-2 дня прием писем со всех доменов.

Вполне возможно, что сейчас у тебя почта уже стала ходить нормально)